# Revert changes of the attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am passing 4 values from my form.

```
attr1
attr2
attr3
attr4
```

On before_save

```
def before_save
  if condition == true
    # here i want to revert changes of attributes ...
    # Right now i am doing this for reverting....
    self.attr1 = self.attr1_was
    self.attr2 = self.attr2_was
  end
end
```

Any better way to revert changes except some attributes ?? I want to revert all the attributes except one or two ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but if you're only doing it on a couple fields, I don't see why you wouldn't just write them out explicitly

```
def before_validation
  if condition == true
    for x in [:attr1, :attr2, :attr3]
      self.send("#{x}=", send("#{x}_was")
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there attributes that can be changed if `condition == true`, if not you can just abort the saving in making the object invalid. You could do it like this:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def validate
    if condition = true
      errors.add(:base,"condition is true")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i don't want to return error. Silently i just want to revert it with last value.